# Gateway architecture design best practices

Tags: architecture, microservices, soa, gateway, api-gateway

I am building a gateway to serve as a proxy infront of a set of downstream endpoint.

One of the requirements is to be able to authenticate/authorise every requests that comes in using jwt ( one of the downstream services will take care of that )

I am considering expressjs for this project.

Is there something wrong if my architecture requires me to send a pr each time i need to expose a downstream endpoint via the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something wrong if my architecture requires me to send a pr
>   each time i need to expose a downstream endpoint via the gateway?

You could realize this via a configuration file defining your endpoints and other required configuration so you don't actually have to touch code.

But generally what is the reason you want to implement your own gateway? There are lots of existing solutions that could possibly save you a lot of time. For example check out [Kong](https://konghq.com/solutions/gateway/), [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/solutions/api-gateway/) or [KrakenD](https://www.krakend.io/).

The benefit with each of those is that beside the authentication they also support features such as monitoring, cache, filtering, throttling, etc., which in most productive environments will come up as requirements eventually.

Comment: thanks @oswin, reason why i wanna create my own gateway is cos my authentication flow is custom.. one of the services behind the gateway acts as an auth service..and i want to authenticate every request that comes through the gateway by a middleware that will call the authService under the hood..that kind of thing.